# c thread in windows HWND error

Tags: c, multithreading

Below is my code.it getting a Handle mistake.

`

```
int main(){

 HWND hMainWin;
 DWORD threadID;
 //Create thread down
 HANDLE threadHandle = CreateThread(NULL,
                              0,
                              threadFunction,
                              (LPVOID)hMainWin,
                              0,
                              &threadID);
 }

 DWORD WINAPI threadFunction(LPVOID param){   //my thread function
 HANDLE hwnd = (HANDLE)param;
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
 printf("hello");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: the message is clear: you're passing an unitialized variable to the thread creation function.

Comment: I didn t understand.How am I going to fix it.

Comment: What value do you think is stored in hMainWin?

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable `HWND hMainWin;` that is not initialized and you are using that (uninitialized) variable as argument #4 in a call to `CreateThread()`. Since the variable is uninitialized its **value** is undefined which is the reason for the error message you are getting.

From the looks of it your code seems to be a **console application**. As such you don't have a *window* or a handle to it (the `HWND`) thus you are having trouble initializing the `hMainWin`.

It looks like that parameter is just a dummy variable (not really used in your thread function) so you might as well (just for a "quick fix") initialize it with a `NULL` (or a `0`)